# AES256 CBC Decryption on Apache on windows7

Tags: apache, encryption

I hope you are well
I want to store information in mysql database through http requests.
I used the xampp package for this. I installed the apache server and MySQL database as well as the php interpreter, and through the mysqli command in the php language, I processed the data in the http requests that were sent to the apache server and inserted it into the mysql database. For example, I would send the following request to the server:
server_ip:server_port/data.php?temperature=10&humidity=20
And the values ​​of 10 and 20 were stored in the temperature and humidity columns, respectively, and formed a row.
But due to security problems, the information must be encrypted and sent to the server. For this reason, I used AES 256 CBC encryption on the client side and send the information to the server, which means the above request looks like this:
server_ip:server_port/OpIAD/E6/hEA3l4p6CRv851CnAFXiX2NzS7Nm0ns/SABrSoow7WK3VhEGEhkV76S
where iv = 1234567890123456 and key = 12345678901234567890123456789012 and the coded part is displayed in base 64 format.
Now the question is, how can this request be encrypted on the server side? What changes should be included in the php settings?

Thank you
Any reply is appreciated

Comment: Just use https and you're done.

Comment: Hello olaf kock.Can you explain more?How can I enable https on apache2? For example I just change my request to: [link](https://serever_ip:server_port/OpIAD/E6/hEA3l4p6CRv851CnAFXiX2NzS7Nm0ns/SABrSoow7WK3VhEGEhkV76S"

Comment: "How can I enable https on apache2?" is a great question for Google, but off topic on stackoverflow, see [help/on-topic]

Comment: but the form of the request must be HTTPS://serverip:httpport/OpIAD/E6/hEA3l4p6CRv851CnAFXiX2NzS7Nm0ns/SABrSoow7WK3VhEGEhkV76S

Comment: In your question, you only said "But due to security problems, the information _must be encrypted_ and sent to the server". That's _precisely_ what https solves, including a level of trust that you know you're encrypting for the correct communication partner (e.g. the server is who it claims it is). There's no need to add encryption of parameters on top of encryption of the connection. And I'd consider it less secure to only encrypt the parameters.